# Rails: Can the bootstrap grid populate from left to right?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am building a products page for an online store and using the bootstrap grid system. Right now when I add items it adds them vertically but I would prefer to add the items horizontally from left to right. Also I am want more then 12 items to show up on one page. Will this happen by default or to I have to change the class="col-lg-12" to something else?

```
 <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Products</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                 <% @products.each do |product| %>
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    <%= image_tag product.image.preview.url %>
                </a>
                 <% end %>
            </div>

        </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you are adding your products in the single column, but what you actually need to do is to add for each product separate column it will look something like this, on each line three products will be displayed

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
         <h1 class="page-header">Products</h1>
       </div>
       <% @products.each do |product| %>
         <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
             <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                  <%= image_tag product.image.preview.url %>
             </a>
         </div>
       <% end %>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Regarding the second part, to have only 12 products on the single page, nope it won't happen auto magically, in your rails app you can use a pagination gem called [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) for the instructions how to use it go the link